# Getting $digest erro error when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to show the User list from SQL Lite Database but when i am binding `$scope.Users` with result.rows, it gives me the following error

> $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in Users">
    <td>
      <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="editUser(u)">&#9998; Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>{{ u.fname }}</td>
    <td>{{ u.lname }}</td>
</tr>
```

controller method:

```
var showRecords = function () // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list
            {
                db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {
                        if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                            dataset = result.rows;
                            $scope.Users = dataset;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Here is [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0fLAtE2erLlKCZyXB50?p=preview)

Please provide me the solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Go thorough this [url](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution now.

Returning data from transaction with SQL Lite Database, need to 
 `JSON.stringify`  
and after that need to parse with 
`JSON.parse`

```
var showRecords = function () // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list
{
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {
            if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.Users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the working [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fbsnkaxf2hytySdL3eB9?p=preview)